# Are these particular kinds of matrices well known?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, matrices, sp.spectral-theory, determinants

Given two positive integers $n$ and $a \leq \frac{n}{2}$ consider a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ such that,

- all the diagonal entries are either $a$ or $a+1$
- all the non-zero off-diagonal entries are $\pm 1$
- if $A_{ii} =a$ then the $i^{th}$ row and the $i^{th}$ column have $a$ non-zero off-diagonal entries. 
  (..and similarly for $A_{ii} = a+1$..)

---

Is something known about such matrices? 
Are they characterized somehow? 
Like what would their maximum eigenvalue be?

Answer (score 7):

[Gerschgorin's circle theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) gives the upper bound $2(a+1)$ for the eigenvalues. This bound should be sharp if I'm not mistaken. I think the family of $n\times n$ circulant matrices
$$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -1 \\
-1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & & \ddots & &  & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 \\
-1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$$
should have maximal eigenvalue arbitrarly close to $2\cdot (1+1)$ (here $a=1$) for $n\gg 0$. If I didn't make any mistakes the eigenvalues of this matrix are $2-2\cos(\frac{2\pi j}{n})$ for $j=0,1,\ldots,n-1$. For $j=\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$ and $j=\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$ this is maximal and arbitrary close to 4, even equal to 4 if $2\mid n$.

EDIT:
And just as I finished writing the first part of this post I remembered the [Perron-Frobenius theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron-Frobenius_theorem). Considere the matrices with constant diagonal $a+1$ and exactly $a+1$ times an entry equal to +1 off the diagonal in each row. These are positive matrices and have constant row sum $2(a+1)$. Therefore this row sum is an eigenvalue with eigenvector $(1,1,\cdots,1)^T$. It coincides with the $\infty$-operator norm (=row sum norm) of the matrix and is therefore equal to the spectral radius. These matrices therefore attain the upper bound exactly.

Comment: In the first part, what you write looks rather like the minimal positive eigenvalue. (For large $n$, it is almost zero).

Comment: You're right. I've corrected that.